# Should I answer questions posted by someone with an unclickable user profile?

Tags: discussion, users

I recently came across a post which I was in doubt of answering. The issue is that the OP's profile is unclickable.

If I answer the question, will the OP be responding to this question? Or is the OP no longer a member and hence should the question be flagged for deletion?

See the unclickable profile below:

[image]

Comment: You can earn valuable reputation from questions for which you'll never get the 'accepted' tick.  For example, my top scoring answer is to [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/) but the OP hasn't been registered for aeons (but was around for some time after the question was asked).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that post is one cool example of this scenario, along with -  *"treat the question on its merits"* as mentioned below by Martin Smith. So i guess iam clear with this- not need to hesitate on answering a post just because the profile is unclickable, provided the post is of good quality

Comment: Obviously, you should test another user, and make sure that is 'clickable' ...

Comment: Effort to blur out username, 10/10.

Comment: Meta meta: emboldening too many words in a piece of text makes it _less_ readable, not more. I see this a lot on the main site, and it's unnecessary - don't use formatting tools just because they're there `:-)`.

Comment: Remember that [so]'s purpose is to build a repository for everyone, not just helping the OP. If the question may be helpful to someone else and is on-topic - **absolutely!**

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If it is a good question and contains all info needed to answer it then yes answer it.

This can happen for two reasons with a 2 minute old question.

- the question was migrated from another site and the OP doesn't have
  an account on this site. In this case they may subsequently create an account and take ownership of the question / be available for clarification.
- The user created an account, posted the question, then deleted the account (or had their account deleted by a moderator). In this case they won't be around to provide any clarifications or accept an answer but the answer may be useful for others.

Comment: I've now found the Question and no I wouldn't bother answering that one, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49717790/73226 it looks highly localised and unlikely to be useful to anyone except the OP who has abandoned it. Looks like they are after general code review anyway.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, so it is better to flag these questions right?

Comment: treat the question on its merits - if it is a good question and answerable then no need to flag anything. If it is a bad question and has been abandoned by the OP they clearly aren't going to be able to improve it so VTC.

Comment: Your answer might help other people, even if the original person that asked it is dead and gone.

Comment: agreeing to @MartinSmith , even if the question is of good quality what if the OP doesn't  `respond/catch-up` with the answer(since if the OP is no longer an SO member, it is obvious that he wont respond) ? in this case the answer may result incomplete and hence no use to others

Comment: @MartinSmith  You should be voting to close a question that can't be answered regardless of the status of the author.  The fact that the author's account is deleted means that you should vote to *delete* the question, once closed, as it has no realistic hope of being improved.

Comment: @Navneetヅ How is the author not being a member going to result in incomplete answers?  Whether the question author has deleted their account or not has no influence on whether a given answer is complete or incomplete.

Comment: @BrianStinar Saying that "the [...] person [...] is dead" kind of has darker implications than what you may mean...

Comment: @Servy i was talking about unclear questions which may need OP's further assistance in answering or even refining the answer

Comment: @Navneetヅ But you opened with "even if the question is of good quality."  If the question is unclear then *it's not a good question*.  Good questions are *definitionally* clear.

Comment: @Servy so if the question is unclear but has a scope of improvement, still vtc?

Comment: @Navneetヅ Yes.  Questions should be closed as unclear when they're unclear.  Deletion is for questions that are unsalvageable.  Closure exists to ensure questions aren't answered until they're improved enough to be in a state where they can be answered.

Answer (score 4):

Without referring to your specific example, if it's a good question you can answer, why not go ahead and answer it? It doesn't really matter if the OP is still around to respond. In fact, often the OP is the most annoying part of answering a question.

Just think of all the things that won't happen if there is no OP:

- After you've provided a perfect answer, they won't edit the question to add some previously secret information that transforms it into something that makes it look like your answer kind of misses the point
- They won't comment "Thank's it worked" on your answer without upvoting or accepting it
- They won't comment "It didnt worked" on your answer without saying why, providing any details that might help you improve it, or responding in any other way ever again
- They won't mysteriously accept a different, blatantly incorrect, and incoherent answer
- They won't say "Awesome, Thanks! Now..." and start dumping new, possibly semi-related questions into the comments on your answer, complete with big illegible code blobs
- They won't inexplicably delete the question right after you answer it
- Probably other things I haven't thought of

The only downside is that they won't accept your answer, something that people attach waaay too much importance to, considering the only real value of an accept vote to an answerer is a few reputation points that won't buy you a cup of coffee and validation from a person who obviously didn't understand the problem initially.

;-)